# Is it possible to remotely control PC/powerpoint slide from bluetooth-enabled phone without having a PC server program?

Tags: powerpoint, smartphone

It looks like most existing remote PC solution using bluetooth-enabled smartphone needs PC side software (especially Java..)

I'm wondering if remote PC control is possible without PC side software at all?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. I once tried Bluetooth remote control with a Sony Ericsson K770i and it worked really great! All you need is a Bluetooth receiver installed on the PC and you need to pair your PC with your mobile phone. Then you can set the phone to control the PC and voila.

I tried this on Windows Vista x86. Worked really great. It was a pleasure to be able to control the PC from my bed when I was sick. Plus, I could bind shortcuts like "Ctrl+C", "Ctrl+V" to certain keys on the mobile phone. The K770i had it all.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sharing your experience, Pateman! Just quick follow-up clarifying question is ... "Buletooth receiver on the PC" you mean is not a special software the user needs to download... But what is it?  To me it still seems to be some software... also is that related to non-socket bluetooth communication (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362942(v=vs.85).aspx) ? I'm just trying to figure out a good starting point/resrouce.. thanks for any comments.

Comment: What I meant was a piece of hardware which receives Bluetooth communication, i.e. a Bluetooth adapter. :)

Comment: After some more research and search, I'm still not 100% clear..From one of powerpointer app, they said that "Please note: You need a small and free server program for the app to run (this is not our fault,
but caused by limited support of bluetooth profiles by Android)".. this means I guess they need HID profile ? Any comment?

Comment: After more search for Sony Ericsson K770i feature, I found that the phone has bluetooth HID profile support, which is possible without PC server as Pateman pointed out... I was looking at android smartphone...and it seems no HID support for android...Anyway, thanks Pateman for your input!

Comment: Yes, from all I've read, there's a limited support for Bluetooth HID in the Android core. I doubt that Google will proritize this much, so it seems you need to look for workarounds.